# udev makes /dev/null unwritable?

Tags: linux, debian, udev

Had two Debian stable (as of 2009-05-28) servers suddenly broken, when /dev/null became unwritable. It appeared that when I restart udev it sometimes (randomly) changes /dev/null permissions sometimes making it unwritable. Server configuration is pretty standard and no udev rules are changed. Does anyone know what kind of a bug this can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this many times, and often it was because the static files were bad.

You might want to try:

```
ls -l /dev/.static/dev/null
```

To see what the boot-time permissions will be, and:

```
chmod a+rw /dev/.static/dev/null
```

To set them

Answer (score 0):

I found this [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=491114) on Debian's website, which was merged with this [one](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=491107). However, they *do* seem to be older than the issue you've just found.

Also, from the Debian wiki on [udev](http://wiki.debian.org/udev), you may be able to look at / fix the init scripts for it.

From a related discussion on Ubuntu, it appears it's been [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/udev/+bug/253786/comments/10) at least there.

Not sure if those'll help/fix you problem, but maybe they're in the right direction :)

Answer (score -1):

Do any of the [issues here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2006-March/069626.html) pertain to your situation?

Comment: I have read this thread. And yes it was similar. But this thread does not resolve anything and I am afraid of next breakdown.